# QhullError (QH6019) in scipy.interpolate.griddata

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, qhull

As part of a larger analysis I am interpolating data at points to a grid using scipy.interpolate.griddata. (scipy version 1.9.3)
Since recently it worked without problems. Now I am getting QHullError QH6019 on one computer, however not on another system. Both are Linux systems with same Python version (3.9.13), venv setup etc. One difference is that on the system that throws the error qhull is installed from the system repositories, while the other does not have qhull as such (I believe scipy brings its own then).

The function that does the interpolation is:

```py
def grid_interp(data, name, xgrid, ygrid):
    '''
    Interpolates point data from geopandas geoseries to a numpy 2D-array of regularly spaced grid points.
    '''
    points = np.vstack((data.geometry.x, data.geometry.y)).T
    values = griddata(
        points, data[name],
        (xgrid, ygrid),
        method=Config.interpolation_method,  # 'linear' and 'cubic' will result in nan outside of the convex hull of data points
    )
    nan_mask = np.isnan(values)  # if there are any nan points re-interpolate them using method 'nearest'

    if np.any(nan_mask):
        values2 = griddata(
            points, data[name],
            (xgrid, ygrid), method='nearest',
        )
        values[nan_mask] = values2[nan_mask]
    return values
```

with `data` being a geopandas dataframe (with geometry projection as EPSG25832), `name` the column name that holds the values to interpolate, and `xgrid` and `ygrid` are the gridpoints resulting from:

```py
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xmin, xmax + xres, xres), np.arange(ymin, ymax + yres, yres))
```

I have seen in other question, that qhull has problems with some projections (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638716/qhullerror-when-plotting-wind-barbs)), however, I know that it works with the current projection from the second system where I don't get the error.

The full error message is:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QhullError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ts/analysis/analysis_geospatial.ipynb Cell 11 in 8
      3 xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xmin, xmax + xres, xres), 
      4                            np.arange(ymin, ymax + yres, yres),
      5                           )
      7 # target_values = grid_interp(station_data, target, xgrid, ygrid)
----> 8 target_values = grid_interp(station_data, 'MassConcentration', xgrid, ygrid)
      9 sedDBD_values = grid_interp(station_data, 'SedDryBulkDensity', xgrid, ygrid)
     11 target_clipped = grid_clip(target_values, poly, xgrid, ygrid)

/home/ts/analysis/analysis_geospatial.ipynb Cell 11 in 7
      2 '''
      3 Interpolates point data from geopandas geoseries to a numpy 2D-array of regularly spaced grid points.
      4 '''
      6 points = np.vstack((data.geometry.x, data.geometry.y)).T
----> 7 values = griddata(
      8     points, data[name],
      9     (xgrid, ygrid),
     10     method=Config.interpolation_method,  # 'linear' and 'cubic' will result in nan outside of the convex hull of data points
     11     # qhull_options='Qz',
     12 )
     13 nan_mask = np.isnan(values)  # if there are any nan points re-interpolate them using method 'nearest'
     15 if np.any(nan_mask):

File ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/ts/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_ndgriddata.py:260, in griddata(points, values, xi, method, fill_value, rescale)
    258     return ip(xi)
    259 elif method == 'linear':
--> 260     ip = LinearNDInterpolator(points, values, fill_value=fill_value,
    261                               rescale=rescale)
    262     return ip(xi)
    263 elif method == 'cubic' and ndim == 2:

File interpnd.pyx:280, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator.__init__()

File _qhull.pyx:1846, in scipy.spatial._qhull.Delaunay.__init__()

File _qhull.pyx:358, in scipy.spatial._qhull._Qhull.__init__()

QhullError: QH6019 qhull input error (qh_scalelast): can not scale last coordinate to [   0,  inf].  Input is cocircular or cospherical.   Use option 'Qz' to add a point at infinity.

While executing:  | qhull d Q12 Qt Qbb Qc Qz
Options selected for Qhull 2019.1.r 2019/06/21:
  run-id 559977496  delaunay  Q12-allow-wide  Qtriangulate  Qbbound-last
  Qcoplanar-keep  Qz-infinity-point  _pre-merge  _zero-centrum  Qinterior-keep
  Pgood  _maxoutside  0
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Actually, I found the problem. Nothing was wrong with QHull, scipy, neither with my code or environment setup.
For some reason a csv file that is read to create the `data` geodataframe, got corrupted on the one system (some numbers lost their decimal separators).

So for anyone landing here with a similar problem: maybe check your coordinates data: in my case it included some `[Inf, Inf]` points originating from invalid LAT LON coordinates in the data source.